# Why does the GCC Compiler not Support #pragma startup and #pragma exit directives?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am a rookie in C language and was trying to learn the #pragma preprocessor directive. I looked up on Google and found this link: [GeeksforGeeks Pragma Directive in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pragma-directive-in-c-c/)

In this link, they said that the `#pragma startup` and the `#pragma exit` Directives don't work in the GCC compiler. Why is it so??

I wrote the same program as given using the MinGW GCC compiler and it said the following warning:

`warning: ignoring #pragma startup func1 [-Wunknown-pragmas]|`

`warning: ignoring #pragma exit func2 [-Wunknown-pragmas]|`

Comment: Neither of those are defined by the C standard, so there is no reason to expect that they would work on different compilers. Per the [gcc docs on pragma](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html), "The `#pragma` directive is the method specified by the C standard for providing additional information to the compiler, beyond what is conveyed in the language itself. . . .  A C compiler is free to attach any meaning it likes to other pragmas."

Comment: @Brian Post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Per [GCC's documentation on pragma](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html),

> The `#pragma` directive is the method specified by the C standard for providing additional information to the compiler, beyond what is conveyed in the language itself. . . .  A C compiler is free to attach any meaning it likes to other pragmas."

Neither of the directives you mention are defined by the C standard, so there is no reason to expect that they would work on different compilers. As mentioned in the article you linked, GCC chooses to use a different vector-specific feature for communicating that a function should be called before or after main, namely [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes).

Answer (score 2):

From gcc website: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html#Pragmas

1. > GCC supports several types of pragmas, primarily in order to compile code originally written for other compilers . Note that in general we do not recommend the use of pragmas.
2. > There is some overlap between the purposes of attributes and pragmas (see Pragmas Accepted by GCC). It has been found convenient to use **attribute** to achieve a natural attachment of attributes to their corresponding declarations, whereas #pragma is of use for compatibility with other compilers or constructs that do not naturally form part of the grammar.

From gcc website, it is very clear that usage of `#pragma` is supported, but not recommeded.

Reference for 2 point :https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes